# Getting Invalid chunk header error in solr?

Tags: tomcat, solr

I am using solr 4.6 over tomcat 7 to index thousand of documents. It works well but frequently i am facing Invalid chunk header error while indexing in solr logs. I have also increased limit of multipartUplaodLimitinKB to 204800000 KB but still its same.

Any help please?

> 974159 [http-bio-8080-exec-82] ERROR org.apache.solr.servlet.SolrDispatchFilter  – null:org.apache.commons.fileupload.FileUploadBase$IOFileUploadException: Processing of multipart/form-data request failed. Invalid chunk header
>           at org.apache.commons.fileupload.FileUploadBase.parseRequest(FileUploadBase.java:367)
>           at org.apache.commons.fileupload.servlet.ServletFileUpload.parseRequest(ServletFileUpload.java:126)
>           at org.apache.solr.servlet.SolrRequestParsers$MultipartRequestParser.parseParamsAndFillStreams(SolrRequestParsers.java:547)
>           at org.apache.solr.servlet.SolrRequestParsers$StandardRequestParser.parseParamsAndFillStreams(SolrRequestParsers.java:681)
>           at org.apache.solr.servlet.SolrRequestParsers.parse(SolrRequestParsers.java:150)
>           at org.apache.solr.servlet.SolrDispatchFilter.doFilter(SolrDispatchFilter.java:393)
>           at org.apache.solr.servlet.SolrDispatchFilter.doFilter(SolrDispatchFilter.java:197)
>           at org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationFilterChain.internalDoFilter(ApplicationFilterChain.java:241)
>           at org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationFilterChain.doFilter(ApplicationFilterChain.java:208)
>           at org.apache.catalina.core.StandardWrapperValve.invoke(StandardWrapperValve.java:220)
>           at org.apache.catalina.core.StandardContextValve.invoke(StandardContextValve.java:122)
>           at org.apache.catalina.core.StandardHostValve.invoke(StandardHostValve.java:170)
>           at org.apache.catalina.valves.ErrorReportValve.invoke(ErrorReportValve.java:98)
>           at org.apache.catalina.valves.AccessLogValve.invoke(AccessLogValve.java:950)
>           at org.apache.catalina.core.StandardEngineValve.invoke(StandardEngineValve.java:116)
>           at org.apache.catalina.connector.CoyoteAdapter.service(CoyoteAdapter.java:408)
>           at org.apache.coyote.http11.AbstractHttp11Processor.process(AbstractHttp11Processor.java:1040)
>           at org.apache.coyote.AbstractProtocol$AbstractConnectionHandler.process(AbstractProtocol.java:607)
>           at org.apache.tomcat.util.net.JIoEndpoint$SocketProcessor.run(JIoEndpoint.java:315)
>           at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor.runWorker(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:1145)
>           at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor$Worker.run(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:615)
>           at java.lang.Thread.run(Thread.java:724)
>   Caused by: java.io.IOException: Invalid chunk header
>           at org.apache.coyote.http11.filters.ChunkedInputFilter.doRead(ChunkedInputFilter.java:172)
>           at org.apache.coyote.http11.AbstractInputBuffer.doRead(AbstractInputBuffer.java:346)
>           at org.apache.coyote.Request.doRead(Request.java:422)
>           at org.apache.catalina.connector.InputBuffer.realReadBytes(InputBuffer.java:290)
>           at org.apache.tomcat.util.buf.ByteChunk.substract(ByteChunk.java:449)
>           at org.apache.catalina.connector.InputBuffer.read(InputBuffer.java:315)
>           at org.apache.catalina.connector.CoyoteInputStream.read(CoyoteInputStream.java:200)
>           at java.io.FilterInputStream.read(FilterInputStream.java:133)
>           at org.apache.commons.fileupload.util.LimitedInputStream.read(LimitedInputStream.java:125)
>           at org.apache.commons.fileupload.MultipartStream$ItemInputStream.makeAvailable(MultipartStream.java:977)
>           at org.apache.commons.fileupload.MultipartStream$ItemInputStream.read(MultipartStream.java:887)
>           at java.io.InputStream.read(InputStream.java:101)

Comment: Appreciate for any help.

Comment: Did you manage to fix this. I am facing the same issue.

Comment: I upgraded memory exposed for Solr in server plus JVM tuning.